# What is the meaning of "anonymous" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> The face of cities in China may be **anonymous**, but the character of residents in these cities is different.

I looked up anonymous in dictionaries. It says if you describe a place as anonymous, you dislike it because it has no unusual or interesting features and seems unwelcoming. But someone told me that native speakers usually use anonymous to describe a name that is not known or that is not made public instead of using the first definition I mentioned. So, I'm confused. Can anybody tell me whether it makes sense to use "anonymous" to describe a place that has no conspicuous features?

The source text wants to say the cities in China look same. So, is it appropriate to use "anonymous" here?

Comment: Have you checked the dictionary definitions of anonymous?

Comment: What did your dictionary tell you about the meaning of *anonymous*?  People asking questions here are expected to have done some research prior to asking a question.

Comment: I looked up anonymous in dictionaries. It says if you describe a place as anonymous, you dislike it because it has no unusual or interesting features and seems unwelcoming. But someone told me that native speakers ususally use anonymous to describe a name that is not known or that is not made public instead of using the first definition I mentioned. So, I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the context is not clear here, the following sentence can be one of the interpretations of the above sentence-

> the cities of China may not appear so obvious to people.

In other words, one can not distinguish/identify cities in China

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

The *literal* meaning of the word is 'nameless', so its principal sense is to refer to a person or place whose name is not known. By extension, it can be used to describe a person or place lacking any distinctive characteristics to make them memorable, or noticeably different from others.

Comment: Get it! Thanks a lot!